# How to cache introspection responses in azure api management

Tags: c#, .net, azure, microservices, azure-api-management

I'm moving authentication from my c# project to azure api management using policies, my code currently is as follows in startup.cs class:

```
services        .AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["OpenIDConnect:Authority"];
                    options.ApiName = configuration["OpenIDConnect:ApiName"];
                    options.ApiSecret = configuration["OpenIDConnect:ApiSecret"];
                    options.EnableCaching = bool.Parse(configuration["OpenIDConnect:EnableCaching"]);
                    options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(configuration["OpenIDConnect:CacheDurationInMinutes"]));                    
                });
```

This works well in c#, the introspection response is cached by EnableCaching and CacheDuration properties, now moving to azure api management, I created the following policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <check-header name="Authorization" failed-check-httpcode="401" failed-check-error-message="Not authorized" ignore-case="false" />
        <set-variable name="token" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","scheme param").Split(' ').Last())" />
        <!-- Validate  -->
        <set-variable name="user-password" value="{{app-client-id}}:{{app-secret}}" />        
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="tokenstate" timeout="20" ignore-error="true">
            <set-url>{{token-validator-endpoint}}</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@("Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)context.Variables["user-password"])))</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@($"token={(string)context.Variables["token"]}")</set-body>
        </send-request>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@((bool)((IResponse)context.Variables["tokenstate"]).Body.As<JObject>()["active"] == false)">
                <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
                    <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized. Invalid or missing access token." />
                    <set-header name="WWW-Authenticate" exists-action="override">
                        <value>Bearer error="invalid_token"</value>
                    </set-header>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <rewrite-uri template="@{
        return "/api/customers/" + context.Request.Url.Path;
        }" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />        
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

How can I cache the introspection response to improve the performance of my apis?

Note: I want to cache it because currently if token gets evaluated for each requests, it adds upto 500 ms of delay to the api response time

Comment: see this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key#fragment-caching

Similar to what you ask